# Bing Maps Rotation

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, rotation, bing-maps

I'm making an App for WP7 and I'm looking for a way to rotate the Map control and the tags (Country, City etc. names). I've been able to rotate the map itself with the transformation properties, but then the text on the map is rotated too.

I've thought of a not-so-pretty solution (not implemented yet) which involves searching the image displayed for text and rotating it back but I don't think that will work quickly enough, and it seems like a waste of battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The country and city names are pre-rendered onto the image tiles requested from the Bing Maps server and you can't separately render the labels from the background - this is how a single tile is served:
[image: Bing Maps Road Tile]

Your only option would be to request unlabelled aerial images from Bing Maps and then place the labels manually yourself from a locally-held set of data. This would require a dataset of all the locations and placenames you wanted to show, together with a label placement algorithm that avoided collisions, optimised for different zoom levels etc. and is unlikely to be practical on a WP7 device.

Comment: Ok, I'll leave it out. It was only a "nice to have" feature anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pretty solution for this! a `RenderTransform` effects an element and all of its children. Why do you think this will not be fast enough? The WP7 screen size is quite small, so I cannot imagine you will have that many labels (TextBlocks) on screen. All you have to do is iterate over them then add a rotation in the opposite direction.

Comment: Well, if there's a say 30 labels on the map and those need to be updated every 100ms or so, added up with the rest of the application logic it wouldn't be a smart thing to do.